# Wordpress how to add custom features to purchased theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a `woocommerce` shop for a customer who has purchased a theme which they want to use. When they create products, they can categorize them and add tags to the products. The user then can navigate to these tag pages, in this case called "product-tag"-pages where they can see all products linked to that tag, for example "Accessories" - the URL would then be `/shop/product-tag/accessories`

So far so good, but the customer wants to be able to add some description text to each product-tag page, but the theme is not laid up for it since there is no template for the `product-tag`-pages and inherits from the parent shop template.

So my question is how could I achieve it add such an text-area to those `product-tag`-pages? Should I listen to the URL? Should I create some `custom post types`?

Any hint is welcome :-)

Comment: In WooCommerce, product-tag pages have the description field which is shown on the frontend. Try to add the description there and check.
If the theme is overriding the template so, you need to check some filter which can be used.

Comment: Its not a big deal to create post types or customize and purchased theme, just you need to know how to do it. You can ask some customization from where you purchased the theme or any others.